# Encoding issue SVN

Tags: centos, svn

I've some users that is using Mac and others Windows, but we have the problem that some files have the name "diseño" or "árbol" and this is causing errors in the clients in mac, and there is some cases where i find duplicate files in the server, something like this name:  "árbol de desición.txt", the file is upload by two diferent users but is the same, and the size is the same too, i think this is encoding issue cause is not recognizing the tilde or the Ñ, how can i resolve or how can I install the svn_1.8.x_darwin_unicode_precomp.patch found in this site:

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2464

I'm using Centos and the last update of the collabnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to install the patch on CentOS.  The Mac Users need to use the patch.  Probably the easiest way for them to get a patched version is to use brew with the `--unicode-path` option when they install e.g. `brew install --unicode-path subversion`.

I'll point out that the patch is not a great fix and can actually cause more problems if it is not used consistently by all the Mac users (which is why it has not been applied to Subversion itself).  There is work underway to solve the problem in a more complete fashion but that work is not complete yet.

Perhaps the easiest solution to this issue right now is to avoid using paths with characters that have composed forms.

There is a rather lengthy document about this in the [notes section of the Subversion source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/unicode-composition-for-filenames) and our [wiki page has some more current thoughts about how to fix it](http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/UnicodeNormalization).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me on OSX El Capitan. The problem in my system was about the repository with the same filename (but just different UTF8 representations in OSX and main svn repo), the solution is to use a patched svn that compares the file names using the "canonical" format of UTF8 filenames; [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2464) you can find additional info about the bug.

I fixed with svn patched, you can find on [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php).

```
sudo port install subversion +unicode_path
```